# How to gift an Apple TV show to someone else (living under Windows)?

Tags: appletv, gift

Is there a way to gift an Apple TV show to someone else?
And is it possible for them to watch it under Windows?

I would like to give the series "Calls" to someone else as a present.
That person, however, lives under Windows.
I guess I could give them an iTunes gift card. (But, maybe, there is a more "dedicated" way?)

But, would it be possible for them to watch the series somehow on Windows?

Comment: Is this more about the gifting or about the “how to watch Apple TV shows on Windows”?

Comment: It is more about how to watch Apple TV on Windows. If that is not possible, then there is no point in gifting an Apple TV show to that person (provided the latter is possible somehow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has documented the various ways to access TV+ on https://support.apple.com/guide/tvplus/welcome/web.

> On a Windows PC (including Microsoft Surface), Chrome OS device, or Android device, you can watch Apple TV+ in the Chrome and Firefox web browsers.
>
> Go to [tv.apple.com](https://tv.apple.com/) to subscribe to and watch Apple TV+ in a web browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realize the browser should work, of course ...

Comment: The remaining (part of the) question now is: is it possible to gift a specific apple show (e.g., Ted Lasso), or just give a general gift card? (I know, I can always write the title of the show on the card myself :-) )

Comment: @gabriel TV+ doesn't seem to allow to gift specific shows